# Oracle Query in XML File

Tags: xml, database, oracle, insert, clob

I would like to have your help because I want to extract the XML string from each record in an XML file, after which I need to insert the selected records into a clob field. I really appreciate your help.

Note: i have the xml structure in Dep.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-
microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2017-09-20T17:59:05"> 
<Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS> </Dep> 
<Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS> </Dep>
```

I want to get this from the query:

```
No. Reg.| XML
   1    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Dep><ID>157</ID><ORDER>7</ORDER><SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep>
   2    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Dep><ID>7</ID><ORDER>19</ORDER><SIGS>PPT</SIGS></Dep>
```

After this; insert the registries into clob field

```
 No. Reg.|CLOB FIELD
    1    |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Dep><ID>157</ID><ORDER>7</ORDER><SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep>
    2    |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Dep><ID>7</ID><ORDER>19</ORDER><SIGS>PPT</SIGS></Dep>
```

Comment: Where is file `dep.xml` located? How do you want to load the file? Is this a one-off exercise or do you need to build a reusable capability? Why is `dep.xml` not a well-formed XML document? Why do you want to store this in a `CLOB` column rather than as an `XMLType`?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can to use [xmlsequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions226.htm) + table functions to extract all depts from xml, and then [getClobVal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm#1015218) to convert XMLType value to the Clob:

```
with t as
(
select XMLTYPE(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2017-09-20T17:59:05"> 
    <Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS> </Dep> 
    <Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS> </Dep>
    </dataroot>') as xml_
from dual
)
select rownum as "No. Reg.", 
       XMLRoot(s.column_value, VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') as XML, 
       XMLRoot(s.column_value, VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8').getClobVal()  as "CLOB FIELD"
 from t, table(xmlsequence(EXTRACT(t.xml_, '/dataroot/Dep'))) s
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, it works but now when i paste the complete XML string; developer sends me this error 01704.00000 "string literal too long" cause: the string is longer than 4000 characters

Comment: @Noé Arciniega, yep, cuz your xml cannot be casted to VARCHAR2 (is a string literal by default). Your should put your XML file contents to the table in CLOB field (select xml_type(YOUR_CLOB_FIELD_NAME) as xml_ from YOUR_TABLE_NAME) or XML_TYPE column (select YOUR_XMLTYPE_FIELD_NAME as xml_ from YOUR_TABLE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/255fd/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE registries (
  id INTEGER,
  value CLOB
);

INSERT INTO registries ( id, value )
WITH xml ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-
microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2017-09-20T17:59:05"><Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep> 
<Dep><ID>157</ID> <ORDER>7</ORDER> <SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep></dataroot>'
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.rn,
       XMLRoot( t.xml, VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8' ).getClobVal()
FROM   xml x
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/dataroot/Dep'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( x.value )
         COLUMNS rn FOR ORDINALITY,
                 xml XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       ) t;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM registries
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/255fd/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                                                                                                VALUE |
|----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Dep><ID>157</ID><ORDER>7</ORDER><SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep> |
|  2 | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Dep><ID>157</ID><ORDER>7</ORDER><SIGS>PPQ (PRAS)</SIGS></Dep> |
```